# How to generate a reverse sequence from this sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I've been having a problem with an algorithm. Assume that there are N people standing in line and each one of them has a number assigned to them (from 1 to N). So if there are 3 people there is one person with number 1, one with 2 and one with 3. They are standing in random order and each has a second number assigned to them that tells how many people are standing in front of them with a number that is bigger than theirs. For example if there are 5 people standing in line and everyone is looking left, we could have this combination: <- 2 <- 3 <- 1 <- 5 <- 4 That means that:

person with number 2 has [0] people standing in front of him with bigger number because there is no one standing in front of him
person with number 3 has [0] people standing in front of him with bigger number despite having 1 people in front of him
person with number 1 has [2] people standing in front of him with bigger number (2 and 3)
person with number 5 has [0] people standing in front of him with bugger number despite having 3 people in front of him
person with number 4 has [1] people standing in front of him with bigger number (5)
So for a sequence [2,3,1,5,4] there is a result sequence of [0,0,2,0,1].

My problem is with a reverse of sorts. How to get the starting sequence having the result as an input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> restoreQueue(const vector<int>& visibility) {
    int n = visibility.size();
    vector<int> queue(n, 0);
    vector<int> numbers(n+1);
    iota(begin(numbers), end(numbers), 0);
    for (int i = n-1; i>=0;i--){
            int counter = visibility[i];
            cout << "Counter: " << counter <<endl;
            vector<int>::iterator iter;
            iter = numbers.end() - 1 - counter;
            int x = *iter;
            cout << "X: " << x <<endl;
            queue[i] = x;
            numbers.erase(remove(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), x), numbers.end());
        }
    return queue;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> visibility = {0,1,2};
    vector<int> queue = restoreQueue(visibility);
    cout << "Starting sequence: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++) {
        cout << queue[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to do this in c++ but the Dave's method doesn't work
EDIT: Thank you Dave for your help, it now works perfectly! If anyone wants, I'll leave the working code above.

Answer (score 5):

Go from the back to the front, interpreting the values as how many values down from the largest value the current value is.

Let's take your example: [0,0,2,0,1]

1. Unk: [1,2,3,4,5], num_greater: 1, so this is 1 down from the largest remaining value, or 4. ans = [?,?,?,?,4]
2. Unk: [1,2,3,  5], num_greater: 0, so this is 0 down from the largest remaining value, or 5.  ans = [?,?,?,5,4]
3. Unk: [1,2,3,   ], num_greater: 2, so this is 2 down from the largest remaining value, or 1.  ans = [?,?,1,5,4]
4. Unk: [  2,3,   ], num_greater: 0, so this is 0 down from the largest remaining value, or 3.  ans = [?,3,1,5,4]
5. Unk: [  2      ], num_greater: 0, so this is 0 down from the largest remaining value, or 2.  ans = [2,3,1,5,4]

From comments: input is [0,0,0,3,1]

1. Unk: [1,2,3,4,5], 1 down is 4, so ans = [?,?,?,?,4]
2. Unk: [1,2,3,  5], 3 down is 1, so ans = [?,?,?,1,4]
   ... rest of these are 0s, so ans will take the remainder in descending order: ans = [2,3,5,1,4]

I think I see what the commenter is doing wrong. 3 down doesn't mean subtract 3, but 3 down the list of remaining values, which is 1, not 2.

Comment: I've tried another example using your method but I went wrong somewhere. Let's take for example: [0,0,0,3,1]

Unk: [1,2,3,4,5], num_greater: 1, so this is 1 down from the largest remaining value, or 4. ans = [?,?,?,?,4]
Unk: [1,2,3, 5], num_greater: 3, so this is 3 down from the largest remaining value, or 2. ans = [?,?,?,2,4]

Comment: Unk: [1,3,5 ], num_greater: 0, so this is 0 down from the largest remaining value, or 5. ans = [?,?,5,2,4]
Unk: [ 1,3, ], num_greater: 0, so this is 0 down from the largest remaining value, or 3. ans = [?,3,5,2,4]
Unk: [ 1 ], num_greater: 0, so this is 0 down from the largest remaining value, or 1. ans = [1,3,5,2,4]
So we get [1,3,5,2,4] which is not the case, because 2 has to 2 bigger numbers before it, not 3.

Comment: @PizzaSmuggler When I say "x down' I mean down the list of unused values, not subtraction. More details added to end of answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer describes a simple approach that uses O(1) extra space, and has O(n^2) time complexity.

The output array is updated one element at time starting from the beginning.

The example input `[0,0,2,0,1]` would result in the following sequence of updates in the output array:

```
[]           start with an empty array
[1]          input[0] can only be 0, so the first output will always be [1]
[1,2]        input[1] is 0, so append the largest value, which is 2
[2,3,1]      input[2] is 2, so increment the two largest values, and append a 1
[2,3,1,4]    input[3] is 0, so append the largest value, which is 4
[2,3,1,5,4]  input[4] is 1, so increment the largest value, and append a 4
```

In pseudocode, the algorithm is:

```
N is the length of the output array.  
X is a number in the input array.  
Y is a number in the output array.  

N = 0  
for each number X in the input array:
   for each number Y in the output array:
      if Y > N-X
         increment Y
   append N-X+1 to the output array
   increment N
```